# Android - Canvas and relative layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas

I am having a problem with stucked canvas where the user should add he's own image then can cover "surround" it with color the problem is that I can't marge relative layout with canvas I tried but I can't , when I move my finger on the screen the Canvas should change the color 
but when I add it to layout I can't do that the color won't change and the cursor Is not moving too , So The Canvas is not activated here's where I set the layout as `contentview`  then adding the canvas to it  the on touch is outside both classes below layout Class
and above Surface Class

```
     setContentView(R.layout.MyLayOutName); 
     canvaslayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyLayOutId);  
    //extending the surfaceview from another class inside layout class
     View = new SurfaceView(this); 
     canvaslayout.addView(ourView);
```

and this is the layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout   android:id="@+id/drawingLayout"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The full code is

[here](http://www.mediafire.com/view/o4abiyibc2npjgp/New+Text+Document+%282%29.txt)

Comment: I see u already hv a surfaceview in xml plus adding another through java code. Is it necessary to do so?

Comment: with the surfaceview in the xml or without it not working but maybe removing the surfaceview class and adding the work in holder method